# HaxeDevelop : project references missing?

Tags: haxe, flashdevelop

I'm using HaxeDevelop for an OpenFL project, and sometimes the project references are missing:

[image: missing haxe, lime, openf libs]

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2):

This could very well be an instance of issue [#1047](https://github.com/fdorg/flashdevelop/issues/1047). You can verify that by checking if the references appear when re-loading the project, as shown in the .gif included in the issue:

[image]

Comment: Yes ! It seems to be exactly that ! 
That's ok for me ... It's definitely a workable 'fix'. Thanks for your help !